# Paypal Payment need transactions details

Tags: php, paypal

I have used paypal payment form submission but in response we didn't get payment status and transactions detail we just geting payer_status.

My code is below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD" >

<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" >

<input type="hidden" value="" name="custom" id="custom" />

<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="" >

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">

<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="" >

<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="" >

<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="" >

<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" >

<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" >             
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="xx">

<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="xx">

<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" >
```

Let me know any solution to get transaction details.

Comment: Where is your code. Your code is empty.

Comment: follow the following articles https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_transaction/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: yes that is right but i wand transaction id in response right now i dont have transaction id and payment_status in response

Comment: you should be clear to your question. Instead of pasting html. you should paste what you have tried yet. we can help you only.

Comment: i have need payment_status in response but didn't get that.

Answer (score 0):

For getting paypal transaction details do follow steps :

1. Auto Return should be "ON" for getting transaction detail via paypal account.

   ```
     a: Login to your paypal account .
     b: Then go to your profile -> myselling tool ->website preference 
     c: Click on the auto return button make it "ON".
     d: And give the return url link on this page .(In my case my app return url is success.php)
   ```

2.When Payment will be successfully completed then provide $_REQUEST array which contains product id, PayPal transaction ID, PayPal received amount value, PayPal received currency type and PayPal product status.
and write this code to your **success.php** page.

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST)) {
    $product_no = $_REQUEST['item_number']; // Product ID
    $product_transaction = $_REQUEST['tx']; // Paypal transaction ID
    $product_price = $_REQUEST['amt']; // Paypal received amount value
    $product_currency = $_REQUEST['cc']; // Paypal received currency type
    $product_status = $_REQUEST['st']; // Paypal product status 
 }
```

I hope this clears up the [paypal](http://www.formget.com/paypal-integration-in-php-using-pdo/) [transactions details](http://www.formget.com/paypal-express-checkout-for-single-product/).